# Beautifulsoup. Result long random string

Tags: python, string, random, beautifulsoup, character

I am learning web scraping, however, I got issue preparing soup. It doesn't even look like the HTML code I can see while inspecting the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.mediaexpert.pl/"

response = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")

print(soup)
```

The result is like this:[Result, soup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roz5w.png)

I tried to search the whole internet, but I think I have too little knowledge, for now, to find a solution. This random string is 85% of the result.

I will be glad for every bit of help.

Comment: It looks like you're getting one of the fonts that the page references.

Comment: The random-looking text is the base64 encoding of the font face.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup does not deal with JavaScript generated content. It only works with static HTML. To extract data generated by JavaScript, you would need to use a library like Selenium.